# Regex: Does not have/include pattern

Tags: regex

I have a regex pattern to match an HTML script tag. How can I change this script tag pattern so that the patterns means "input string DOES NOT MATCH" the script tag pattern?

In other words, given a pattern, what is the alteration needed to change the meaning of the pattern to "does not match this pattern"?

For example, if I have a pattern: `\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{4}`, what is the equivalent pattern for this that means "does not match `\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{4}`"?

Comment: Err... why not a simple `somestring!="<script>"`?

Comment: Can't you just use `!` to boolean negate the match? I.E. `!preg_match("\d{3}", $string);`

Comment: It's probably easier to change the logic that uses the pattern (e.g. `if !regex.match()`) instead of trying to change the pattern itself.

Comment: sometimes you can specify the regex but cannot change the code logic, so a anti-match regex is desired.

Answer (score 3):

You can negate a regex pattern by using a negative lookahead.  This is slightly different than simply negating the regex though.  Negative lookahead would look like the following in Java (and many other languages):

```
(?!\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{4})
```

It should be noted that this doesn't exactly answer the question.  Finding the inverse of a regular language is not an easy task using a regular expression (I don't think).  A much easier way to solve the problem would be to inverse the program logic:

Instead of:

```
if (string.matches(yourRegex))
```

Do:

```
if (!string.matches(yourRegex))
```

Comment: @ElR, I don't think it's the best solution.  But it does answer the question that the OP asked.

Comment: Although of course this won't actually 'match' a string which is not the OPs original match. But I don't know what they're trying to achieve.

Comment: @ElR, right.  It will match the string, but it won't capture the group.

Comment: This doesn't quite answer the question, how do you propose to use `(?!\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{4})` to match strings not containing the OPs pattern?  The regex by itself matches `_123-456-7890_`, something is missing!

Comment: @Andrew, I'm not sure if finding the inverse of a regular language can even be done with a regular expression.  I'm just suggesting one possible solution to look into.  The best way would be to just inverse the logic of the code.

Comment: Fair enough, it just seems like that information should be in your answer.

Comment: There might be something I am missing, but I think that `(?!.*\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{4})` is a complete regex for this use case?

Comment: @Andrew, I'm having a hard time wrapping my head around matching the inverse of a regular language.  I'm not 100% sure what would work in his case.

Comment: @jjnguy: I agree with the notion that you should just invert the match, so belated +1 for including that. @jjnguy, @Andrew Clark: Don't forget the Pumping Lemma-- maybe there's a way to show that a "negated" regex isn't regular? (You only need an existence proof to show that inverted regex isn't regular!) I'll look into that when I get home from work.

Comment: @Plat, don't remind me of the Pumping Lemma! Thanks for the +1 though.

Comment: @jjnguy: Actually I think an inversion of a regular expression IS regular. This is because all regular languages can be both expressed with a regular expression AND also represented with a finite automaton. And in the case of the finite automaton, if you just switch what states are accept states and which are not, then you have a machine that matches exactly the complement of the original regular language. Because this new machine is still a finite automaton, it does describe a regular language! ...The tricky part is trying to find a regular expression to describe the new automaton, though...

Comment: @Plat, Yeah! You are bringing back some scary memories from my days in college.  You are correct though.  Thanks for the refresher course.

Answer (score 1):

That is not easily achievable for arbitrary patterns. In practice, it's almost always easier to do what you want in the surrounding code than in the pattern itself. For instance, instead of

```
grep '\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{4}' file
```

you could use

```
grep -v '\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{4|' file
```

Or in a program you could change something like

```
if (pattern.matches()) {
    foo();
}
```

into something like

```
if (!pattern.matches()) {
    foo();
}
```

In a more tedious approach, you would have to enumerate all possible values that *should* match instead of what should not match. So, say you want to match everything but the string `<html>`, you could write a regex like so:

```
([^<]|<([^h]|h([^t]|t([^m]|m([^l]|l[^>])))))
```

Reading that regex is like saying: "Okay, you can match any character but '<', or you could match '<' but then you can't match an 'h' after that... or you do match an 'h' after that but then you can't match a 't' after that... and so on.

It's butt ugly, but then again, for simple string matches, you can easily write a recursive function that transforms any given term into a pattern like the above.

Answer (score 0):

easier to just negate the test surely? eg...

```
if (!regex.test(str)) ...
```

(javascript example)

Negating a character class is easy with `^` but a whole regex will get much more convoluted.

Answer (score 0):

What language are you using? The easiest solution to the specific problem you stated is to simply prepend a negation operator (usually "!") to the match.

Answer (score 0):

I definitely agree with the other answers saying you should negate testing for a match, but this should do what you want using just a regex:

```
(?!.*\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{4})
```

This is a negative lookahead, by not placing any characters outside of the lookahead the regex basically means "fail on any string that starts with any number of characters (`.*`) followed by the regex `\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{4}`".